# edit:SQL multiple table instances

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
SUBSCRIPTION

NAME SUBSCRIBER
```

It's essentially a table having a list of people who subscribe to each other. I want to write a query that outputs a list of tuples such that, if the set B represents all those people who subscribe to A, B also represents those people that A doesn't subscribe to. ie, find a list of people who are not mutually subscribed to each other.

This is the query that I wrote:

```
SELECT A.name, B.name 
FROM subscription AS A, subscription AS B 
WHERE A.subscriber=B.name AND A.name!=B.subscriber;
```

ie, it should display two columns A and B where B subscribes to A and A doesn't subscribe to B.

All I'm getting is garbage with a lot of rows duplicated. What am I doing wrong in this?

Well, I made a mistake while stating the samples. The samples go like this:

Melissa, Joan subscribe to John.
Charles, John subscribe to Joan.
Charles subscribes to Melissa.
melissa, joan subscribe to Charles.

the first part refers to the subscriber column and the second to the name column.
ie, John's the name and melissa, joan subscribe to john.

therfore, it should output (melissa,john) because john doesn't subscribe to melissa.

How would this change the query?

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result on your question? it helps alot :D

Comment: Is there a primary key associated with this table? Using the above query will give you a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) which it sounds like is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pulls all records from the subscription table where there isn't a corresponding match in the subscription table for the opposite subscription.

```
select subscriber, name
from subscription a
where not exists (
  select 1
  from subscription b
  where a.subscriber = b.name
        and a.name = b.subscriber)
```

Comment: Also, when I try the same query by replacing not exists with exists and changing the second exprn in the subquery to a.name!=b.subscriber, I don't get the same results. Why though?

Comment: Think of it this way. You are selecting the entire table and then evaluating a predicate against it. In my query, you're only returning rows that don't have a corresponding a.name = b.subscriber. In your query (changing not exists to exists), you're returning all rows such that there exists a row in the table where a.name != b.subscriber. So in your sample data you specified to Brent, even though (Melissa, Joan) exists, it will return because there exists a row in the table where Melissa is the name and Joan is not the subscriber (Melissa, Charles).

Comment: Thank you ! If possible, I edited the question.. could you try answering that too.. i made a mistake.. im still learning so Id be most grateful for anyhelp.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do a LEFT JOIN. That will return all A names and link them to all B names. There will be at least 1 record for each A name, but possibly many. Up to how many B names are subscribed to name A. If there is no B subscriber, then there will be one A name, but the B column will have a value of NULL.

```
SELECT A.name, B.name FROM subscription AS A 
LEFT JOIN subscription AS B ON A.subscriber=B.name AND A.name!=B.subscriber;
```

Comment: Well, these are the samples: John subscribes to Melissa, Joan. Melissa subscribes to Joan, Charles. Charles subscribes to Melissa and John,  Joan subscribes to  Charles. So  the output I need is (Melissa,John), (Joan,John),(Joan,Melissa),(John,Charles),( Charles,Joan), (John,Charles)etc where the second person subscribes to first. (melissa, joan ) will not make the list because they subscribe to each other...  Name has the values John, Melissa, Charles and Joan and subscriber contains maps to the names of people who subscribe to them...In reply to JoHn Woo :)

Comment: there is no primary key associated with this table.. Ryan Gates.

Comment: Well, as I understand.. LEFT JOIN would be INNER JOIN + values on A that don't have a match.. I tried your query. I just got the same table with the garbage.. in reply to  Brent Baisley